# Android Studio always create .c file when do NDK,why?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

My Android Studio is at version 2.3.3.

I create a new project step by step following this instruction:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html.

Since i selected "Include C++ support ", so i noticed the IDE created a native-lib.cpp for me.And I found it's CMakeLists.txt as well;

I want to add my own native method and my own "so" library,like that:

```
static{System.loadLibrary("test")}
public native int GetNumber();
```

As per the instruction,i updated the CMakeLists.txt and added my .cpp/.h files in CPP directory.

But,when I press alt+enter accroding to Android Studio's tips to generate autoly
the method,I found IDE create a new .c file in CPP directory meanwhile generate the method there.

I've tried several times,always same.

I'm confused and want to know how can I make the .cpp file works!thanks!

Comment: I've solved this problem.It's a little bit tricky.

Comment: I recreate a new project without "include c++ supprot".and I build a "CMakeList.txt" myself. When I wanna generate the native method,AS create a new .c file anyway. So,I delete the .c and create a .cpp file myself meanwhile copy the native method from .c to .cpp.

Comment: Then,everything looks better.I could use .cpp files in AS. .c file never comes again.

Comment: AS will add the native method to .cpp file,wow!